# Warning: usage of [lint] does not match the tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 948 questions tagged [lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lint), and 1428 questions tagged [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis). Of the 948 questions tagged [lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lint), only 69 are tagged with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), which means that the vast majority (> 90%) of questions tagged with [lint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lint) aren't about the lint utility itself. However, the tag wiki says

> **Usage of the Stack Overflow "lint" tag**
>
> Only use this tag for questions involving the various Lint tools from
>   [Gimpel Software](http://www.gimpel.com/html/index.htm).
>
> Please refrain from using this tag regarding general questions about
>   static analysis. Questions in regard to the static analysis of code
>   and the use of static analysis tools should use [static-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-analysis).

I've just now added that instruction to the wiki excerpt, but I'm happy for it to be reverted.

How should we ensure that tag usage is consistent with what the wiki recommends? Should we retag questions that aren't tagged "correctly", rename the "lint" tag to something that indicates that it's a specific tool (eg "lint-utility"), create a synonym "linting" to "static-analysis", or something else?

Comment: I totally thought it was for questions about sorting balls of pocket lint.

Comment: I had a look at the Gimpel Software site linked from the wiki. The main takeaway was that their software isn't actually called "Lint". The appropriate tag for it appears to be [tag:pc-lint], possibly with [tag:flexelint] as a synonym.

Comment: In addition to duplode's suggestion, my first impression of [tag:lint] tag is *any* lint tools because that's the term I learnt on certain IDEs (e.g. [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint)). I don't think limiting [tag:lint] to Gimpel is a good idea because I consider that "too localize". Perhaps after renaming the software to a better tag, synonymize [tag:lint] to [tag:static-analysis].

Comment: @TinyGiant I was disappointed at the lack of belly button questions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would be in favor of duplode's solution: Use Gimple's names for Gimpel's tools. [lint] is still a useful tag, for the family of [c] [static-analysis] tools modelled on the original UNIX `lint`.

There are static analysis tools for non-C languages, and those are not known as Lint, so I wouldn't be in favor of making [lint] a synonym of [static-analysis]. We don't have tag taxonomies, so we can't do hypernyms. Still, wouldn't hurt to put in cross-references in the tag excerpts.

Comment: We still refer to PHP static analysis from the command line as lint, although lint-mode is probanly more correct.